# Unrar-free doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

So this is the error i'm getting

```
ubuntu@ip-my-ip:~/mt2$ unrar-free -x -p smon.rar
Password:

unrar 0.0.1  Copyright (C) 2004  Ben Asselstine, Jeroen Dekkers


Extracting from /home/ubuntu/mt2/smon.rar

Extracting  smon.vdi                                                  Failed
```

I can unrar the file on windows,it works tested!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use the non-free `unrar` package?

```
$ apt-cache show unrar
Package: unrar
Priority: optional
Section: multiverse/utils
Installed-Size: 244
Maintainer: Ubuntu MOTU Developers <ubuntu-motu@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Martin Meredith <mez@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Source: unrar-nonfree
Version: 1:3.9.3-1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1)
Conflicts: rar (<= 2.60-1)
Filename: pool/multiverse/u/unrar-nonfree/unrar_3.9.3-1_amd64.deb
Size: 102356
MD5sum: 992124eae32ccaba5e91d95dac4d4fa0
SHA1: df0526a43f0adc6ab5ef7848112fcad39bce877e
SHA256: b929a9b81891d76a93de9c0a2298f87bcc932d3991cfa1b0498bafa34ff0afe9
Description: Unarchiver for .rar files (non-free version)
 Unrar can extract files from .rar archives. If you want to create .rar
 archives, install package rar.
Homepage: http://www.rarlabs.com/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

"nonfree" is related to the license.  The non-free version is more recent than the unrar-free one.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-dadada:~/mt2$ apt-cache show unrar
N: Can't select versions from package 'unrar' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found

Comment: It's in the "multiverse" repo.  Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and uncomment the "multiverse" repo.

Comment: "nonfree" in this case refers to (among other problems) the fact that it costs money to use.  You should read the license carefully before using this software

Comment: why unrar-free doesn't work on most files like these?